# Output of shell script run on Windows contains prompt

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

I have a Python script which is running a shell script using the `subprocess` library. It has to run on any platform so I have 2 shell scripts, one for Linux/MacOS (`cm`) and one for Windows (`cm.cmd`).

Let's say they both contain just a single command `example_command -param`.

The code which is running the shell script looks like the following:

```
json = subprocess.run(['cm'], shell=True)
```

This way, thanks to the shell handling the execution of the script (`shell=True`), it runs the script `cm` on Linux/MacOS platforms and `cm.cmd` on Windows.

The output of the script is a JSON and it works properly on Linux/MacOS platforms, the only problem is with Windows where the output contains the shell prompt which breaks the JSON obviously.

The captured output in the `json` variable may look like this:

```
My prompt c:\ $ example_command -param
{ "json_data": ... }
```

How to avoid printing of the prompt to the subprocess output?

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the feature called *command echoing* which is enabled by default but it may be disabled using the [`echo` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo). From the documentation:

> #### Syntax
>
> `echo [on | off]`
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `[on | off]`  Turns on or off the command echoing feature. Command echoing is on by default.

If you add `echo off` at the first line of the script, it will disable the *command echoing* for all subsequent commands but it will echo the `echo off` command itself. To suppress even echoing of that command, simply prefix it with `@`.

At sign (`@`) as a command prefix has the same effect as `echo off` but only for a single command.

So to summarize it: **Simply add `@echo off` at the first line of the shell script** (or batch in Windows terminology) and that's it. Only the output of command(s) executed in the script will be sent to `stdout`.